# Flutter local notification action button click not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-notifications

I have been trying to get by action buttons on my local notifications to work. but I cannot get anything to print on the console when it is clicked (the app is running in foreground). I am using **flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.1**

All project setup has already been done according to [Setup instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-android-setup).
I want to note most examples and tutorials online launch the notification from main.dart. But in my case its Main.dart -> LoginPage -> HomePage(notification called in init method)

I have tried running the [example app](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/lib/main.dart#L96) of the local notifications package which runs fine and trigger the action button events fine. I have also copied part of the function that launches the notifcation over to my NotificationService Class with no success. I did some code comparision and for the most part did not find any major code differences between mine and the example app (but i might be missing something thats staring at me)

In the HomePage init method im calling the NotificationService Class, which is setup according the documentation, as follows:

```dart
NotificationService notifService = NotificationService();
    notifService.showNotificationWithActions(
      "Test Notification",
      "Your have changes that needs approval.",
      actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
        const AndroidNotificationAction(dismissNotifID, 'DISMISS',
            cancelNotification: true),
        const AndroidNotificationAction(approveChangesID, 'APPROVE',
            cancelNotification: false),
        const AndroidNotificationAction(viewChangesID, 'VIEW',
            cancelNotification: false),
      ],
    );
```

Notification display has no issues. but clicking on approve or view does not print what I want to be printed. However, the console does show the following:

> W/ActionBroadcastReceiver(26591): Callback information could not be retrieved

And every consquent button press just repeats this line

> E/ActionBroadcastReceiver(26591): Engine is already initialised

I just cannot seem to get anything else to print on the button press event which. What am I missing or doing wrong here. Any help on this is appriciated. Directions, code help, suggestions..

NotificationService Class

```dart
class NotificationService {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<bool?> initializeService() async {
    _notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    // Initialization setting for android
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("ic_dol_notification");

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: null,
    );

    return await _notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
          (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
        print('onDidReceiveNotificationResponse');
        print('notification(${notificationResponse.id}) action tapped: '
            '${notificationResponse.actionId} with'
            ' payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    print('notificationTapBackground');
    print('notification(${notificationResponse.id}) action tapped: '
        '${notificationResponse.actionId} with'
        ' payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
  }

  final String highGroupKey = 'dolphin.high';
  final String maxGroupKey = 'dolphin.max';

  final String highGroupChannelId = 'HighImportanceNotifs';
  final String highGroupChannelDescription =
      'notification channel to show normal notifications including errors and normal msgs';
  final String maxGroupChannelId = 'MaxImportanceNotifs';
  final String maxGroupChannelDescription =
      'notification channel to show duty change alerts and other alerts that need immediate user attention';
  final String workingNotifChannelId = 'BackgroundWorkOnProgressNotifs';
  final String workingNotifChannelDescription =
      'Shows up when background work is currently ongoing';

  final String highGroupChannelName = 'Normal Notifications';
  final String maxGroupChannelName = 'Duty change Alerts';

  /* 
  this function was copied directly from example project
  hoping it would work. it yeilded same results as any other
  */
  int testid = 1;
  Future<void> showNotificationWithActions(String title, String msg,
      {List<AndroidNotificationAction>? actions}) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
            channelDescription: 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker',
            actions: actions);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
    );
    await _notificationsPlugin.show(testid++, title, msg, notificationDetails,
        payload: 'item z');
  }

  /// Use this for errors and other msgs
  /// @params [title] title of the notification
  /// @params [msg] body of the notification
  void showHighNotification(String title, String msg,
      {List<AndroidNotificationAction>? actions}) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails highNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      highGroupChannelId,
      highGroupChannelName,
      channelDescription: highGroupChannelDescription,
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.high,
      groupKey: highGroupKey,
      actions: actions,
    );

    NotificationDetails highNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: highNotificationAndroidSpecifics);

    await _notificationsPlugin.show(
      612,
      title,
      msg,
      highNotificationPlatformSpecifics,
    );
  }

  /// Use this for Duty Changed notifications
  /// @params [title] title of the notification
  /// @params [msg] body of the notification
  void showMaxNotification(String title, String msg,
      {bool dismissable = true,
      List<AndroidNotificationAction>? actions}) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails maxNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      maxGroupChannelId,
      maxGroupChannelName,
      channelDescription: maxGroupChannelDescription,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
      groupKey: maxGroupKey,
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      showWhen: true,
      visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
      category: AndroidNotificationCategory.reminder,
      actions: actions,
      ongoing: !dismissable,
    );

    NotificationDetails maxNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: maxNotificationAndroidSpecifics);

    await _notificationsPlugin.show(
      832,
      title,
      msg,
      maxNotificationPlatformSpecifics,
    );
  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue: On the first click on a notification action button, I received:

```
W/ActionBroadcastReceiver(26591): Callback information could not be retrieved
```

Every consquent button press printed this:

```
E/ActionBroadcastReceiver(26591): Engine is already initialised
```

The solution was to add 'showsUserInterface: true', in my case:

```
actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
      AndroidNotificationAction(
        'yes_action', // ID of the action
        'Yes', // Label of the action
        showsUserInterface: true,
      ),
      AndroidNotificationAction(
        'no_action', // ID of the action
        'No', // Label of the action
        showsUserInterface: true,
      ),
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by adding `showsUserInterface: true` like so:

```
    NotificationDetails(
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
          interruptionLevel: InterruptionLevel.timeSensitive,
          categoryIdentifier: 'cat_1',
          badgeNumber: 0,
        ),
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel_notifs',
          'Local Notifications Channel',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          actions: [
            AndroidNotificationAction('action_1', 'Action 1', showsUserInterface: true),
            AndroidNotificationAction('action_2', 'Action 2', showsUserInterface: true),
          ],
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
            action.text,
            contentTitle: action.title,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

You can read more in the official docs: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#notification-actions

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue too, what resolve my issue was adding a request permission to show notification at the splash/homepage.

Here's the code

```
Future<void> _requestPermissions() async {
if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS) {
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.requestPermissions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.requestPermissions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? androidImplementation =
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();

  final bool? granted = await androidImplementation?.requestPermission();
  setState(() {
    _notificationsEnabled = granted ?? false;
  });
}
```

Hope it fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

> W/ActionBroadcastReceiver(26591): Callback information could not be
> retrieved

I could solve the problem by putting the notification setup (notificationsPlugin initialize and other notification listener) in the main function before the runApp function

Comment: Adding a few lines of code might be a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the action in the background and not set `showsUserInterface: true`, your notificationTapBackground needs to be either top-level (outside your class) or static, like so:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
 static void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    print('notificationTapBackground');
    print('notification(${notificationResponse.id}) action tapped: '
        '${notificationResponse.actionId} with'
        ' payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
  }
```

Again, it must be either **top-level** or **static**, as per the docs here:

[image]

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#notification-actions

Answer (score 0):

Do this, edit the initialization method:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationResponse(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  print(notificationResponse.actionId); // Returns the action key only when an action button is clicked
  print(notificationResponse.payload); // Returns the payload irrespective of which part of the notification was clicked
}

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationResponse,
  onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationResponse
);
```

Note that when setting the notification action for Android don't forget to add the `showsUserInterface` property and set it to `true` like this:

```
AndroidNotificationAction('ACTION_OK', 'Ok', showsUserInterface: true);
```

This will make the response callback to detect and return the action key set above.

For more insight, you can check the documentation please: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-usage

Remember this function runs (except Linux) in a separate isolate! This function also requires the `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` annotation to ensure that tree-shaking doesn't remove the code since it would be invoked on the native side.